# JSON.net parsing of dynamic JSON

Tags: json, json.net

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "OK"
    },
    "data": {
        "_idtype": "cusip",
        "_id": "00768Y883",
        "api": {
            "_name": "PortfolioBreakdownsRaw",
            "PortfolioDate": "2015-10-12",
            "GlobalBondSuperSectorLongSalePositionBreakdown": [
                {
                    "Name": "Municipal",
                    "Value": "0.57842"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Corporate",
                    "Value": "1.79649"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Securitized",
                    "Value": "5.29493"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Cash & Equivalents",
                    "Value": "166.20776"
                }
            ],
            "GlobalBondSuperSectorShortSalePositionBreakdown": [
                {
                    "Name": "Government",
                    "Value": "0.90557"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get the `api` portion of the response easily:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var api = jObject["data"]["api"];
```

From here, I don't what if any arrays will be included in the response.  The ultimate goal will be to create a parser that will be able to get the array names (`GlobalBondSuperSectorShortSalePositionBreakdown`) and as many rows of key-value pairs that it may contain, without first knowing the names such as (`GlobalBondSuperSectorShortSalePositionBreakdown`) beforehand.

I can't seem to find a good way to loop through the object, determine there are arrays at the `api` level and then iterate through those to get the values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to build a list of dictionaries out of the elements which are arrays under the `api` element, right ? excluding all  elements which are not arrays, such as `_name` and `PortfolioDate` and also, assuming that all those arrays are key/value pairs, and you will not have arrays which don't match that condition, is it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example.  In this code, the `api` variable holds a `JObject`, so we can iterate over its properties.  From there, we look at the `Type` of each property value to see if it is an array or not.  If it is, then we can iterate over that array to get the `JObjects` within it, and extract the `Name` and `Value` values that we expect to find there.  Does this help?

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var api = jObject["data"]["api"];

foreach (JProperty prop in api.Children<JProperty>())
{
    JToken value = prop.Value;
    if (value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": ");
        foreach (JObject jo in value.Children<JObject>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   " + jo["Name"] + ": " + jo["Value"]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
_name: PortfolioBreakdownsRaw
PortfolioDate: 2015-10-12
GlobalBondSuperSectorLongSalePositionBreakdown:
   Municipal: 0.57842
   Corporate: 1.79649
   Securitized: 5.29493
   Cash & Equivalents: 166.20776
GlobalBondSuperSectorShortSalePositionBreakdown:
   Government: 0.90557
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XyoXQy

Comment: This works great, thanks so much.   I had some of the bits and pieces in your answer, but I could not get it all together.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Linq you can play pretty nice with Json.net:

Here is an easily readable version of the chunk of code that will create two dictionaries out of the JArray properties under the api element:

```
var api = jObject["data"]["api"];
var arrays = api.Cast<JProperty>().Where(o => o.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array).Select(token => token.Value).ToArray();

var dictionaries = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
foreach (var array in arrays)
{
    var dictionary = array.ToDictionary(token => token["Name"].Value<string>(), token => token["Value"].Value<string>());
    dictionaries.Add(dictionary);
}
```

**alternative:**

The same thing, but a shorter, more compact version :

```
var api = jObject["data"]["api"];

var dictionaries = api
    .Cast<JProperty>()
    .Where(o => o.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    .Select(token => token.Value)
    .Select(array => array.ToDictionary(token => token["Name"].Value<string>(), token => token["Value"].Value<string>()));
```